# AWS CLI S3 COPY Command Get FINDSTR Error Due to Too Long Variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

When I copy file to S3 bucket with variables by AWS CLI, I got error.

-- command with variables

```
aws s3 cp %SRC_FILENAME% s3://%S3_BUCKET%/%DEST_FILENAME%
```

-- error message

```
FINDSTR: 1 行目は長すぎます。 (original)
FINDSTR: TOO LONG 1st.line (translated)
```

If I set the source and destication S3 bucket file name without any variable, it ends successfully as usual. And 'aws s3api put-object' command designated by same logic (variables), never encountered same issue.

-- command without variables

```
aws s3 cp G:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.bak s3://<S3_bucketname>/<TAG>/<FILENAME>
```

-- s3api command with variables

```
set S3API_COMMAND_STR=aws s3api put-object --bucket %S3_BUCKET% --key %DEST_FILENAME% --body %SRC_FILENAME% --metadata md5chksum=%SRC_HASH% --content-md5 %SRC_HASH%
```

I think aws s3api command is more better, but sometimes I need to send over 5GB file, so tentatively should select aws cp command at this point.

I thought this issue can be caused by the length limitation of Windows variables, s3api command with variables should be more longer variables though...

If someone had encountered the same issue, please let me know how you handled. Any advice would be appreciated.

Sincerly.

< Additional Infromation >
Just tentative workaround, once output the command line and execute it, then it worked successfully.

```
echo %S3_COMMAND_STR%  > temp_cmd.bat
call temp_cmd.bat
```

But still not sure why this findstr error occurred on aws cli, so any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI.

Still not sure why AWS CLI would accept it, but following either of workaround goes successfully, too.

```
aws s3 cp %SRC_FILENAME% s3://%S3_BUCKET%/%DEST_FILENAME% & if ErrorLevel 1 goto ERR_S3_UPLOAD
```

or

```
set S3_COMMAND_STR=aws s3 cp %SRC_FILENAME% s3://%S3_BUCKET%/%DEST_FILENAME%    
%S3_COMMAND_STR% & if ErrorLevel 1 goto ERR_S3_UPLOAD
```

Comment: @Hadi, Thank for your other kind advice :)